# Simplifying in Algebra

Tags: calculus

can someone tell me how this equation is simplified? i am unable to understand how the negative sign b - a is changed and why a which is out is removed.

[View Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FqBI.png)

Comment: Are you familiar with the distributive property?

Comment: No, actually I am learning mathematics by self study. let search it.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Answer (score 1):

$1a+\frac{1}{2}(b-a)$

$1a+\frac{1}{2}b-\frac{1}{2}a$   <-- distributive property to multiply

$1a-\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b$   <-- commutative property

$(1-\frac{1}{2})a+\frac{1}{2}b$  <-- distributive property to factor

$\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b$      <-- did 1-1/2

$\frac{1}{2}(a+b)$               <-- distributive property to factor

Comment: That's great explaination. thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What they did is the following without explicitly writing it.
$$a+\frac{b-a}{2}$$
$$\frac{2a}{2} + \frac{b-a}{2}$$
$$\frac{2a + b -a }{2}$$
$$\frac{a+b}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}&\quad a+\frac{1}{2}(b-a)\\
&=a+\frac{1}{2}b-\frac{1}{2}a\quad\text{(distributive law)}\\
&=a-\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b\quad\text{(commutative law)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}a+\frac{1}{2}b\quad(a-\frac{1}{2}a=a(1-\frac{1}{2})=a\big(\frac{1}{2}\big)=\frac{1}{2}a)\\
&=\frac{1}{2}(a+b)\quad\text{(distributive law)}\end{align}$$

Comment: In 3rd step why did we changed sign and in 4th step where is "a" gone

Comment: Edited my answer.